# What is the optimized implementation of conflict graph for combinatorial auction?

Tags: java, optimization, graph

Given m bids that may share a subset of n items, I want to find the best way to store conflicts among bids and check whether two bids are conflicting (i.e., they share at least one item). So far, I have tried a matrix of dimension m x m which isn't optimal. My problem may have thousands of bids, therefore I frequently get the error "Java out of memory space" when I use the square matrix implementation. Then, I tried with a triangular matrix (because the original conflict matrix is symmetric) but without getting rid of the memory issue!

Any better idea?

The best way to code?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to store conflicts exactly? Why don't you detect conflicts on demand?

Comment: That's good question. The answer is simply because my algorithm may encounter the same couple of bids several times to check if they are conflicting. I am doing a local search that iterates thousands times, at each step it must check any conflict in current solution (subset of bids). While computation time is a concern, the on-demand conflict check is worth a trial, at least I  will alleviate memory space restriction to the number of bids. Thanks.

Comment: Are your matrices sparse (ie. contain many non-conflicts)? I assume you're aware of sparse matrices, but you don't explicitly state it, so I'm just asking.

Comment: No, the matrice isn't sparse; many bids are conflictual.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use Guava's `Table` and combine it with a `List<Bid>` containing all bids. Note: below code uses a lot of Guava goodness:

```
final List<Bid> allBids = Lists.newArrayList();
final Table<Bid, Bid, Void> conflicts = HashBasedTable.create();
```

When you store a new bid, you'll do (this supposes that `bid` has an `.items()` method which return a `Set<Item>`):

```
for (final Bid bid: allBids)
    if (!Sets.intersection(newBid.items(), bid.items()).isEmpty())
        conflicts.put(newBid, bid, null);
allBids.add(newBid);
```

Then when you want to detect a conflict between two bids:

```
return table.contains(bid1, bid2) || table.contains(bid2, bid1);
```

---

You could even store the conflicting items by replacing the `Void` values with `Set<Item>`s instead and put the result of `Sets.intersection()` in it:

```
// Table becomes Table<Bid, Bid, Set<Item>>
Sets.SetView<Item> set;
for (final Bid bid: allBids) {
    set = Sets.intersection(newBid.items(), bid.items())
    if (!set.isEmpty())
        conflicts.put(newBid, bid, set.immutableCopy());
}
allBids.add(newBid);
```

Comment: In your first code, you should mean: removeAll instead of retainAll.
Anyway, I am already detecting conflict more efficientely than you suggest, what I don't do efficiently and thus I am asking about is conflict storage? thanks

Comment: No, I do mean `.retainAll()`. The goal is to detect whether two bids share items. Therefore we retain from the items in the first bid all items that are also in the second bid. If there are no common items, nothing is retained.